# How is the bandwith calculated in Weka KernelEstimator class?

Tags: java, statistics, weka

I am using Weka to calculate the probability for a given dataset. More specifically I am using the [KernelEstimator](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc/weka/estimators/KernelEstimator.html) class.

For good density estimation results the choice of the bandwith parameter is crucial, but I have not been able to find out how the bandwith parameter is calculated. The kernel function being used is a simple [Gaussian Kernel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_kernel). Does anyone know how the bandwith parameter is calculated?

Comment: Not an actual answer, but have you tried reading the code? Weka is GPLed.

Comment: I tried reading the code, but could not figure out how the bandwith is calculated.

Answer (score 1):

You can find it [here](https://svn.scms.waikato.ac.nz/svn/weka/trunk/weka/src/main/java/weka/estimators/KernelEstimator.java):

There you will find

```
m_SumOfWeights += weight;
double range = m_Values[m_NumValues - 1] - m_Values[0];
if (range > 0) {
  m_StandardDev = Math.max(range / Math.sqrt(m_SumOfWeights), 
      // allow at most 3 sds within one interval
      m_Precision / (2 * 3));
}
```

m_StandardDev is what it uses later on as the "variance" of the Gaussian kernels, i.e., your bandwidth.